# How to create an array of dimension n+1 given a function returning an array of dimension n

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

With numpy and python3 I have to following problem:

I have a function which returns a 2 dimensional array of integers of fixed size (2x3 in this case). What is the most idiomatic way to run this function `n` times and stack these together to a 3 dimensional 2x3xn array? What about performance? Something which only does the minimum number of allocations would be nice.

Comment: For actual performance, it would make sense to know about the implementation of that function itself. It could probably be vectorized with NumPy ufuncs and such.

Comment: `Something which only does the minimum number of allocations would be nice.` - that's C++-style thinking. Allocation isn't what's going to kill your performance in Python. If you try to run this function `n` times instead of taking advantage of NumPy vectorized operations, interpreter overhead is going to kill your performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for [`np.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arrs = [np.random.rand(2, 3) for x in range(5)]
>>> np.dstack(arrs).shape
(2, 3, 5)
```

If you know the final shape you can do something like the following:

```
>>> out = np.empty((2, 3, 5))
>>> out[..., 0] = np.random.rand(2, 3)
```